# When i increase the font size div border size is also increasing

Tags: javascript, html, css

why the div border size is increasing when the font size is increased.

here is the link to js fiddle:

```
LINK TO JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/krishna22211/m14qms52
```

Comment: That's because you are using ems as the measure unit for the border, which is relative to the font size, so when you increase your font size the border increases as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em units are **relative to the font size**. As your border width is in em units, as your font size increases so will your border.

If you don't want this behaviour, simply don't use em units for your borders (as you want them fixed size anyway).

Comment: oh thanks .. i don't know about this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms you are using Em as a unit which is relative to many other measurement related stuff, font size being the most significant among them. Changing one size or measurement will effect the other. 
Even though i prefer to use em most of the time as it does not hurt the design much when resolution is significantly changed or when you try to 'zoom in' (In firefox sites that use em work way better when zoomed in or out).

Answer (score 0):

min-height:100px; is there means no maximum limit and height is auto,
use

```
   max-height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;
```

then border wont increase.